# Second Woocomerece add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I need to create a second button on product pages next to the current add to cart button.

Currently I have a button that says 'Add to basket' and when clicks it adds the product to the basket but doesn't redirect to cart.

The second button needs to add to cart and redirect to the basket or checkout page.

Any ideas on how i can create this button?

Comment: Welcome to SO, This question is way too broad, Please take a minute to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [Writing the perfect question.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and try writing a better question, showing us what you have tried already and where you are stuck. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use javasctip's
button + ajax
submit

Comment: Why you have answered without reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) This shows wrong impact on other users. Also it look a like that you are playing and enjoying with others that what will happen next. I suggest to remove the answer or update your answer in brief.